# Certain fields are disabled while editing a node

Tags: nodes, forms

I created a page named "welcome"; when I try to edit the contents of the page when logged in as admin (uid=1), I find that the "input format," "menu settings," "revision information," and "comment settings" fields have been disabled.

Could anyone help me with how to enable these fields?

I am using Drupal 6. It is not a fresh install.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you editing as uid=0? And how to create the same problem in both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7? What else is installed? Can you repeat it on a clean install?

Comment: no.the uid is 1.you could find the image in the following link since i did not have any permission to upload it here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850643/certain-field-are-disabled-while-editing-the-contents-of-a-page

Comment: Edit your question with uid, drupal version and info is it clean install or what else do you have. Then we'll be able to answer - maybe.

Comment: First thought it was something relate to the permission.I have checked the permissions and its all correct

Comment: Is there something that am missing..???

Comment: Check the Javascript console in your browser.

Comment: I kno its a bit akward but when i replace the system's table in my project and replace it with a fresh one i get what is desired.so i don't think that it might b something related to javascript.

Comment: Have you installed ckeditor in this site? Once i faced similar situation like it as no filter format was specified neither full html, by the way i know that plain text is default to every one. But you can check it and try it might help you..

Comment: Tanx for the reply @mohit.I have'nt installed it..can it be caused by a contributed module..??

Comment: I do had a hook_init() function which caused me the above problem.Don't know what the error had to do with this hook function.But after i removed my hook_init function i solved that mess... Tanx everyone :)